# What Format is this List in?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm receiving data in the format:

```
"result": {"FirstData": {"One": 1, "Two": 2,...
```

First of all, what is this called usually in Java (2D array)?

Secondly, how do I loop over this to extract the strings?

I understand that if I only had "FirstData" in my array I can do:

```
public void onSuccess( String[] result)
{   
    for( String Name : result ) {
        System.out.println(Name);   
    }
```

Going through the same logic for 2D arrays, it doesn't seem to print things out:

```
public void onSuccess( JSONObject result)
{   //Parse here

    }
```

EDIT:

Yes it's JSON and it looks like the code has gson (google JSON) installed

EDIT 2:

ABOVE CODE NOW CORRECTED

Comment: looks like json format

Comment: Yes it is, but then how do I extract those values if that's the data coming back?

Comment: This looks like JSON, but it does not look like a list.

Comment: It's not my code that I'm editing, it's a program I have to add a mod to. 

So I have this part: `service_.Values(myarray , new AsyncCallback<String[]>() {`

I tried changing it to `<String[][]>` but that stopped me from getting a response

Comment: He's asking for the java object that he can deserialize that data into.  Please stop telling him it's JSON!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks kind of like JSON. JSON-strings is built like this:

Key: Values

However, Values can be new "key:values" so you can have:

"Key": ["InnerKey1":"Value1","Innerkey2","Value2"], "Key2": ["InnerKey1":"Value1","Innerkey2","Value2"] etc.

For you source:

```
  JSONObject myJSONObject = new JSONObject("Your resultstring goes here");
JSONObject resultObject = myJSONObject.getJSONObject("result");
JSONObject FirstDataObject = resultObject.getJSONObject("FirstData"); //Object with JSONObjects "One","Two" etc


//Since the part " {"One": 1, "Two": 2,..." in your string isn't an JSONArray you cannot do the following but if it were like this "["One": 1, "Two": 2,..." your could do this:

JSONArray FirstDataArray = resultObject.getJSONObject("FirstData"); //Array with JSONObjects "One","Two" etc

JSONArray arr = resultObject.getJSONArray("FirstData"); 
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String number = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString(0);
    ......
}
```

Comment: how would you use this in this situation though?

Comment: See my edited answer (haven't tested the code for typos and so on)

Comment: Thankyou for trying, I'll have a go with this now =)

Comment: For reference, I was following this: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideMakingACall

Comment: It was almost what you said but at least you got me closest to being on track, above code now amended

Comment: some of those methods you gave me aren't part of JSONObject such as getJSONObject

Answer (score 2):

JSON. Use a [JSON parser](http://www.json.org/) to read the data. One popular parser for Java : [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: A link to Jackson or Gson would probably be more helpful than a link to the JSON spec.

Comment: @chrylis If you scrolled down to the link I provided, you would have seen google-gson there. Anyways, I added google-gson if that matters.

Comment: So I have the google library gson installed, do you have a quick example of what this would look like to parse the above data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Google Gson, https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/. It can take JSON strings and convert them to Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parser for Java and you can probably convert it into objects. You can find a variety of Java-based JSON parsers on http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

This string is in the JSON format and hence it is recommended to use a JSON parser.

Read about JSON format in http://www.json.org/.

This link provides explains about JSON in java http://www.json.org/java/